# No puedo ejecutar un .jar con JavaFX 14.0.1 y OpenJDK 14.0.1

Tags: java, javafx, jar

Estoy desarrollando aplicaciones Java y me he cambiado a **OpenJDK 14.0.1** junto con la librería **JavaFX SDK 14.0.1**. Actualmente estoy desarrollando con **Apache NetBeans 11.2** y me surge un problema, de otros muchos que he solucionado ya.

Resulta que al compilar una aplicación con NetBeans, puedo ejecutar esta (.jar normales), con swing y librerías básicas. Pero no pasa lo mismo al ejecutar un .jar que tiene las librerías de JavaFx. Me aparece este error en consola:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

[image: Imagen del error]

Ahora viene lo mejor, si ejecuto este mismo programa en NetBeans, funciona:

[image: Imagen de la aplicacion funcionando]

Al generar el "jar" mete todas las librerías que supuestamente necesita en la carpeta "lib".

[image: Imagen de las librerías]

Aún así no funciona. Tengo las bibliotecas de JavaFx en todos los sitios donde ha de estar dentro del proyecto.

[image: Librerias incorporadas al proyecto y a NetBeans 11.2]

He consultado ni sé la de veces por aquí y por allá, he resuelto varios problemas pero este, este me está dejando sin neuronas. Si alguien arroja algo de luz le estaré bastante agradecido, no tengo profesores a los que preguntar ahora mismo.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Comparte el modo en que ejecutas la aplicación

Comment: Lo hice mediate un archivo .bat el cual pone:
`java -jar %1`

De otra forma no puedo apuntar al open jdk, también probé con esto, la útlima línea, ya que las otras eran para compilar y no me permitían porque faltaba el main o algo así.

`java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFx.jar`

[Link de la fuente original](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)

Comment: Se me olvidó decir que el proyecto de JavaFx contiene un archivo **.fxml** para la vista, con su respectivo controlador.